What is a space which is the cross product $D^2\times S^1$?
While taking cross product of two one-spheres, $S^1\times S^1$ seems esasy to imagine/identify with a torus $T^2$, I struggle to make a picture of a $D^2\times S^1$, what kind of a space is that in general? I tend to confuse as there are "intersections" if one think of it as usual solid torus. Since in the case if the radius of the $D^2$ is larger than the $S^1$,
Pardone me if it is nonesense to talk about
"radius" and all in topology and a possible ambiguity of the term "intersection".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus

is $S^1\times D^2$ the same thing as $D^2\times S^1$?

It depends on what notion of "same"ness you're looking for, but in almost every reasonable sense of the word "same", they are the "same" space: homeomorphic, diffeomorphic, isometric (with the right metrics), etc.

I guess the operator $\times$ is referred to as the cartesian product, and it is argued that it is not commutative
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

@EdenZane It is not commutative on the nose, but $X \times Y \cong Y \times X$ via $(x, y) \to (y, x)$ for any $X$, $Y$ (for any reasonable sense of $\cong$, in particular homeomorphism, to essentially restate what Kyle says).

ok. that makes it clear.. thanks
